# TLS connection refused with nothing on logs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssl, nginx

I've been attempting to install an SSL certificate for the past several hours to no success. There are no errors on the nginx log, but everytime I try to access my website through https I just get a connection refused.

I've tried everything I can find on Google and SO results:

- I've disabled the Ubuntu firewall
- I've run netstat and there's an active listen on port 443
- I've verified the sha256 checksum of the certificate, private key and certificate requests
- service nginx restart + service nginx status shows everything ok

I feel like I'm arriving at the limit of my experience with nginx (which isn't much) and Linux, so I turn to SO for help.

Here's a redacted copy of my nginx.conf, which proxies the requests to a Node.JS server:

```
server {
    listen my.ip.address:80;

    listen my.ip.address:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/my-server.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/my-server.com.key;

    server_name my-server.com;

    client_max_body_size 700m;

    root "/var/www/my-website/";
    access_log "/var/www/my-website/logs/access_log";
    error_log "/var/www/my-website/logs/error_log";

    location / {
        proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
        proxy_send_timeout   600;
        proxy_read_timeout   600;
        proxy_buffer_size    64k;
        proxy_buffers     16 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
        proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_hide_header  Vary;
        proxy_set_header   Accept-Encoding '';

        proxy_pass http://my.ip.address:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Accel-Internal /internal-nginx-static-location;
        proxy_no_cache $arg_aid;        
        access_log off;
    }

    location /internal-nginx-static-location/ {
        alias /var/www/my-website/;
        add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
        add_header X-Powered-By nginx;
        internal;
    }
}
```

I'm running nginx 1.10.3 on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by a nano .conf.save backup on the nginx /sites-enabled folder which had a misconfigured https server declaration - I was not aware that nginx loaded files other than .conf.

Answer (score 1):

Add below line before "ssl_certificate xxx" line and try

ssl on;

Updated:

Can you try with this simple config.

```
upstream myapp {
    server http://my.ip.address:8080;
}


server {
    listen 443;
    server_name mywebsite;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/app_access.log  main;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/app_error.log;

    ssl    on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/nginx.key;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://myapp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have tried that as well, was my previous config which is, from what I see, deprecated. The reccomendation for version 1.10.* is to to `listen my.ip:port ssl`

Comment: i have updated the answer , can you please try and check the logs if you see any error.

Answer (score 0):

'Connection refused' means that nothing was listening at the target IP and port you tried to connect to.

It has nothing to do with HTTPS, TLS, SSL, or certificates whatsoever.

Comment: Could be nothing listening, or could be a firewall in the path with a `REJECT` rule.

Comment: As mentioned in the OP, netstat shows there's something listening on port 443. Also, Ubuntu firewall is disabled